# Can PCA output features be applied before Naive Bayes Algorithm - Apache Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, pca, naivebayes

I'm a newcomer to Apache Spark and was wondering if it is possible to apply PCA to a dataset before applying the Naive Bayes algorithm to train a model, in Apache Spark?

Right now, the following shows my code:

```
        Dataset<Row>[] splits = data.randomSplit(new double[] {0.7, 0.3}, 54321);
        Dataset<Row> trainingData = splits[0];
        Dataset<Row> testingData = splits[1];
        

        /* I want the 30 output features of the following line*/
        PCAModel pca = new PCA().setInputCol("features").setOutputCol("pcaFeatures").setK(30).fit(data);
        
        NaiveBayes bayes = new NaiveBayes();
        /* To become the input for this classifier*/
        NaiveBayesModel model = bayes.fit();
        bayes.setLabelCol("label").setFeaturesCol("pcaFeatures");
        
        
        Pipeline pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(new PipelineStage[] {model});
                
        
        PipelineModel modelx = pipeline.fit(trainingData);
        
        Dataset<Row> predTraining = modelx.transform(trainingData);
        Dataset<Row> predTest = modelx.transform(testingData);
```

Comment: I have also tried: 

NaiveBayesModel model = bayes.fit(pca.transform(trainingData));

However, I get the following error: requirement failed: Column pcaFeatures must be of type double but was actually struct<type:tinyint,size:int,indices:array<int>,values:array<double>>.

Comment: Are you facing any problem while using above vode?